# Utilizar Regex em switch no jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

Galera, to com uma dúvida aqui e não sei se é possível fazer o que quero (acho que sim). A dúvida é, tenho um switch(link) e segue exemplo dos cases (link de exemplo):

case "http://www.link.com.br/exemplo/": break;

case "http://www.link.com.br/exemplo/index.html": break;

case "http://link.com.br/exemplo/": break;

case "http://link.com.br/exemplo/index.html": break;

e preciso fazer isso com vários links. Tem alguma forma, usando Regex, de verificar em um case se a url possui ou não esse www. e o /index.html para não ficar criando várias linhas desnecessárias? (Obs.: se for o caso, pode ser com if/else).

Comment: Não percebí o que queres fazer... queres detectar `www.` na string? e fazer o quê se tiver?

Comment: Sim, quero fazer algo que, se houver ou não o www. ou /index.html ele execute tal função. Esse foi um código de exemplo, na realidade ele vai executar uma função em cada case...

Comment: E precisas de regex para isso? Podes fazer com `if (url.indexOf('www.') != -1) fazer algo...`

Comment: Eu gostaria do regex simplesmente para não ter que fazer isso, nesse caso teria que fazer várias verificações. O que eu queria mesmo seria case "http://(se tem ou nao www.)link.com.br/exemplo/(se tem ou nao index.html)": break;
para não precisa criar várias linhas de códigos desnecessárias.

Comment: O url começa sempre com `http://`? O dominio é sempre o mesmo?

Comment: Sim, exatamente.

Comment: Testa assim `if (/http:\/\/(www\.)?.*(index\.html)?/.test("http://link.com.br/exemplo/")) fazer algo...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão de RegExp:

```
/http:\/\/(www\.)?.*(index\.html)?/
```

Para testares podes usar assim:

```
var regex = /http:\/\/(www\.).*(index\.html)/;
if (regex.test(url)){
    // fazer algo quando tem "www." e/ou "index.html"
} else {
    // não tem
}
```

A regex tem dois grupos de captura opcionais para "apanhar" essas strings.

Porém acho melhor fazer isto em JS com indexOf:

```
if (url.indexOf('www.') != -1 || url.indexOf('index.html') != -1){
    // fazer algo quando tem "www." e/ou "index.html"
} else {
    // não tem
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou em nenhum dos casos, Sergio. Vou postar o código que estava desenvolvendo para vc poder entender o que eu estava querendo evitar. E, previamente, muito obrigado por se oferecer a ajudar.

Comment: Esse era o código: http://pastebin.com/fGChdnfp
Olhando, vc poderá ver minha intenção, que no caso era o de evitar tantos cases, utilizando o regex...

Comment: @Igor há mais cases que esses? Esse é o código todo? Senão parece-me que só precisa de saber quando o link tem `/galeria/`, é esse o padrão que precisas defenir, nada mais.

Comment: Não, e preciso saber do contato também. Na realidade deu pra entender mais ou menos o que eu pretendo com o código? Até eu estou confuso agora :(.

Comment: Na realidade não precisaria mesmo do /index.html. Eu havia pensado nisso para questões de segurança (evitar que a função não execute caso for o index.html) mas, pensando bem, acredito que sem o index.html não vá fazer diferença...

Comment: @Igor para mim só precisas disto: http://pastebin.com/EaaazpMs

Comment: Perfeito, @Sergio. Como não pensei nisso antes? As vezes eu penso tanto em como fazer tal coisa que acabo me enrolando e fazendo da maneira mais difícil. Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @Igor ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.